# Retrieve XMLHttpRequest (XHR) response from webpage with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xmlhttprequest, selenium-chromedriver, response

Is there a way to retrieve the XHR response data with Python or Selenium WebDriver? Right now I can only view the XHR response data through the 'Network' tab in the 'Inspect' tool in the browser. What I have currently :

```
url = 'url'
response = requests.get(url)
json_value = response.text
print(json_value)
```

But this returns 'Please contact the site administrator.'. 
Just wondering if there is a workaround with Selenium to retrieve XHR response?

Comment: Wondering the same, let me know if you ever find out.